# Polymer paper element not working in android phone

Tags: javascript, android, webview, polymer

I am using polymer paper elements in my polymer app. Its looking great in all desktop browsers. I tried [this demo](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/demo2.html) in all browsers. It working nice in some android phones (samsung s4). But in some android phones, I could not see anything (Tested using chrome and default android browser on samsung gt i9070, Micromax A90). I tried to load URL of mentioned demo on  [android webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), It was not working in many phones (Micromax canvas A114).

I gone through [browser compatibility page](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/compatibility.html) Which shows, It supports in chrome android. but not observed by me. Is this observed by others ?

Comment: This is probably something you should talk to the Polymer developers about.

Comment: Just for clarity, what version of Chrome are you running on the  samsung gt i9070, and Micromax A90? You can see this when you tap Help and Feedback at the bottom of the context menu, near the URL.

Comment: I found that Polymer 1.0 not working on Sony Ericson XPERIA default browser. It throws an exception "Window is not defined"

Comment: This confirms it: https://github.com/meteorpoly/polyscope/issues/2